# Navigate to screen so confused with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a bottom navaigator as follows:

```
BottomNavigator
      Home           -> (Profile Screen)         
      StackNavigator
            Menu     -> (Profile Screen)
```

My Question is -

> where should I put the Profile Screen to navigate from both Home &
>   Menu Screen to make sense.

**Thanks & sorry about my English.**

Comment: Ya react-navigation confuses a lot at the start. No issues we are here to help u. Pls explain ur question a bit detailed

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `BottomNavigator` and `ProfileScreen` with New stackNavigator as below. 
And do not forget to give some options.

For example,

```js
StackNavigator
 ㄴBottomNavigator
   ㄴ ...
 ㄴProfileScreen
```

```
const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Bottom: BottomNavigator,
  Profile: ProfileScreen 
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    mode: 'modal',
    header: none,
  }
})
```

It makes you can call `Profile` from anywhere.

```
navigation.navigate('Profile')
```